# Работа таймеров в .NET

Tags: c#, таймер, .net

Дело такое: есть метод, который должен выполняться **часто** по таймеру, но выполнение метода может затягиваться (например, interval = 100 мс, время выполнения = 2-3 с). Какой таймер как себя будет вести? В частности, мне нужно исключить параллельное выполнение метода.

Пробовал тестировать вручную с `System.Timers.Timer` - получается что-то странное: метод вроде как запускается параллельно, но меньшее кол-во раз, чем должен бы (т.е. не каждые 100 мс). Для `System.Threading.Timer` результат такой же должен быть, так понимаю? `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` пока трогать не стал.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как оно работает? Или где почитать можно по теме?

Comment: Сразу важный вопрос: в каком потоке должен работать метод? Поскольку метод длинный, это не может быть UI-поток, правильно? По этой же причине вы не имеете права блокировать поток, в котором приходит оповещение от таймера (каким бы этот поток не был).

Comment: Почитал Ваш ответ и понял, что я ничего не знаю )
UI-поток - это поток, в котором идет отрисовка форм, я так понимаю? И запускать метод в этом потоке плохо, т.к. формы будут подвисать, да? Значит, надо создавать отдельный поток и таймер запускать оттуда?
Вообще же я подумал и понял, что мне таймер не особо и нужен - достаточно просто отдельного потока, который будет в цикле вызывать метод и спать, если надо.

Comment: @djebedia: (1) да, это поток, в котором происходит отрисовка UI. Запускать в этом потоке медленные функции плохо, и правда будет подвисать.

(2) Смотрите, как работают таймеры. System.Windows.Forms.Timer доставляет event'ы в UI-поток, т. к. это обычно то что требуется (раз) и туда можно пробросить свой код из-за event loop'а (два). System.Timers.Timer так не может, т. к. он вовсе не знает о том, что есть какой-то UI-поток (он не зависит от наличия UI), и поэтому доставляет event'ы в свой собственный поток. Если вы в этом потоке выполняете длинный метод, вы блокируете своевременную доставку...

Comment: @djebedia: ... последующих event'ов в этот поток, т. к. поток не может одновременно и выполнять ваш метод и обрабатывать event.

Мне тоже кажется, что хорошим решением будет выгрузить «длинное» задание в отдельный, специально выделенный для этого поток.

Comment: Согласен, для этих целей можно использовать класс Parallel или Task